# Can you help me get my menu working on mobile?

Tags: html, css

I've managed to put a great looking menu togheter!`

```
<li class="huvudmenu"><a href="index.html">Framsida</a></li>
    <li class="huvudmenu">
    <a>Om oss</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="styrelsen.html">Styrelsen</a></li>
      <li><a href="historik.html">Historik</a></li>
      <li><a href="Stadgar.html">Stadgar</a></li>
      <li><a href="topeliuspriset.html">Topeliuspriset</a></li>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">HTML</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">CSS</a></li>
      </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="huvudmenu"><a href="verksamhet.html">Verksamhet</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Hangö seminariet</a></li>
        <li><a href="arsberattelser.html">Årsberättelser</a></li>

      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="huvudmenu"><a href="estholmen.html">Estholmen</a></li>
    <li class="huvudmenu"><a href="blimedlem.html">Bli medlem</a></li>
```

`http://jsfiddle.net/hx6uvc19/ The setup I have does not, unfortunatley, work very well on touch screen devices. Is there any way I can keep the design while making it touch screen compatible?

Thanks!

Comment: rather than just have a hover effect, you can use a script to toggle that 'hover' effect on a click handler

Comment: Did this help your problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can not use the `:hover` pseudo class on mobile. In order to get this effect you can use JQuery as stated by @jbutler483 in the comments.

If you wanted to do this you could do it by adding an `.active` class to the main `li`'s (By using the class `.huvudmenu`) on click/touchstart and add this to the css where you have your hover styles as well.

This is the JQuery:

```
$('.huvudmenu').on('click touchstart', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).toggleClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
});
```

and the styles to add are:

```
nav ul li.active > ul {
    display: block;
}
```

and

```
nav ul li.active:after {
    width: 100%;
    background: #404040;
}
```

this will then allow the styles on click and touchstart events. If you wanted this to only run on mobile you could just remove the click and use touchstart events and/or put some kind of detection that this is a mobile device before initialising the JQuery function.

Here is an update to your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/lee_gladding/hx6uvc19/3/